# Unable to create an object of type 'PrattleContext' when trying to connect to value from appsettings.json from data layer

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

My application is layered like so

API -appsettings.json

DAL -configs -appsettings -contexts -mydbcontext

I am simply trying to pass my connection stirng in app settings to my dbcontext through projects and run migrations.

When I hit dotnet ef migrations add initial

I get the error

```
    PM> dotnet ef migrations add changing
    Build started...
    Build succeeded.
    Unable to create an object of type 'PrattleContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
    PM>
```

My program.cs file (in api project)

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using prattle.Data.Configs;
using prattle.Data.Contexts;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

//db
builder.Services.AddDbContext <PrattleContext> (option =>
    option.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("prattleDatabase")));

builder.Services.Configure<AppSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").GetSection("prattleDatabase"));


builder.Services.AddOptions();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

appsettings.json (in api project)

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "prattleDatabase": "Host=localhost; Database=prattle; Username=develop; Password=develop123;"
  }
}
```

configs/appsettings ( in data layer )

```
namespace prattle.Data.Configs
{
    public class AppSettings
    {
        public string prattleDBConnectionString { get; set; }
    }
}
```

contexts/prattlecontext ( in data layer )

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using prattle.Data.Configs;
using prattle.Model.Models;

namespace prattle.Data.Contexts
{
    public class PrattleContext : DbContext 
    {
        private IOptions<AppSettings> _appsettings;

        public PrattleContext()
        {

        }


        public PrattleContext(IOptions<AppSettings> appsettings)
        {
            _appsettings = appsettings;
        }


        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {

            var dbConnectionInfo = _appsettings.Value.prattleDBConnectionString;

            optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(dbConnectionInfo);

        }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Message> Messages { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm guessing the issue is in my program.cs file, but I can't work out why?

Comment: So did you go to the link given in the error message?

Comment: ...yes but like i said im not sure what the issue is....

im not sure if its a dbcontext issue, or a connectionstring issue beacause if i hardcore the connection string like so :              optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("Host=localhost; Database=prattle; Username=develop; Password=develop123");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `builder.Services.Configure<AppSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").GetSection("prattleDatabase"));` will not work as you expect, `prattleDBConnectionString` will be `null`. To make it work you need to match name of json property and property of class which represents settings:

```cs
public class AppSettings
{
    public string prattleDatabase { get; set; }
}
```

Then to bind it correctly you need to use only `ConnectionStrings` section:

```cs
builder.Services.Configure<AppSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));
```

Also note that the setup via options you are using is not an idiomatic way to manage EF Core context, usually you need only one [ctor accepting `DbContextOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#dbcontext-in-dependency-injection-for-aspnet-core):

```cs
public class PrattleContext : DbContext
{
    public PrattleContext(DbContextOptions<PrattleContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    // ... db sets
}
```

So `AddDbContext` call works with parameters specified there.

The last thing you are potentially missing is the parameters passed to the `dotnet ef ...`. For starters since it seems you are using Visual Studio package manager console you can switch to commands [supported by it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=vs#evolving-your-model) (Powershell), like `Add-Migration`. They will use "defaults" from your VS - "Default project" (set it up to the project with the context):

[image]

And the Startup project selected in the solution explorer (select the API one).

If you still want to use [dotnet ef tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#common-options) you may need to specify next options:

| Option | Short | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `--project <PROJECT>` | `-p` | Relative path to the project folder of the target project. Default value is the current folder. |
| `--startup-project <PROJECT>` | `-s` | Relative path to the project folder of the startup project. Default value is the current folder. |

With `-p` set to the project containing the context and `-s` set to the API project with connection string.

Comment: hey Guru, thanks for this it was really helpful, one point I am unclear is the ctor: i need to DI my    private IOptions<AppSettings> _appsettings;, do i that in a constructor aswell?, so in effect I have 2 constructors?  like so? 
        public PingContext(IOptions<AppSettings> appsettings)
        {
            _appsettings = appsettings;
        }

        public PingContext(DbContextOptions<PingContext> options)
             : base(options)
        {

        }

Comment: edited previous comment ^

Comment: @dros why do you need `IOptions<AppSettings> _appsettings`? especially why do you need connection string there? But in general - no, you don't need to have 2 ctors, you just add the parameters to the one you have. `PingContext(DbContextOptions<PingContext> options,IOptions<AppSettings> appsettings) ... `

Comment: i have appsettings to contain the connectionstring so that I can pass it into onconfiguaring like so         protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {

            var dbConnectionInfo = _appsettings.Value.pingDBConn;

            optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(dbConnectionInfo);

        }

Comment: @dros you don't need to do it. Just use the ctor as I showed and EF will handle the connection string.

Comment: so my context is now as follows 
    public class PingContext : DbContext
    {

        public PingContext(DbContextOptions<PingContext> options)
             : base(options)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {


        }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

however when i run dotnet ef migrations add initialCreate 

I am still getting the Unable to create an object of type 'PingContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, message

Comment: @dros - see the rest of my answer. have you specified startup-project and -project parameters correctly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246942/discussion-between-dros-and-guru-stron).